# How to use github musicmetadata library in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ionic2

working on some ionic 2 music player. I wanted a way to read media tags for a music file and i found musicmetadata to be well ok. Below is how its used according to the documentation:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var mm = require('musicmetadata');

// create a new parser from a node ReadStream
var parser = mm(fs.createReadStream('sample.mp3'), function (err, metadata) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(metadata);
});
```

The problem here is `fs.createReaderStream` throws an exception : webpack_require_i and i have no idea what it it. So i was wondering is there a way to get this working in ionic 2 or is there any other media tags reader out there that could work with ionic 2.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using [this library](https://github.com/leetreveil/musicmetadata).

To import in typescript, you need type declarations of the library. It seems to be available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/musicmetadata). You will find type declarations for most javascript libraries in [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped).

Do:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/musicmetadata
```

This will save the declarations as dev dependencies as you wont need it after transpiling to javascript. Here is your type declaration [file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/musicmetadata/index.d.ts)

In your code,

```
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as mm from "musicmetadata";

let parser = mm(fs.createReadStream('sample.mp3'), (err, metadata) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(metadata);
});
```

Comment: With your example am getting a :

Comment: Runtime error__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_fs__.createReadStream is not a function

Comment: hmm.. fs is a node module server side.. dont think it is included in browser

Comment: That means I'll have to find w way to read the file stream using the ionic native file plugin

Comment: Thanks, would try that out and see how that goes

Comment: Actually doesn't seem simple than I thought, how exact do I get the media plugin to work with musicmetadata because the musicmetadata accepts and internal.Readable as its first argument and I don't think I can convert the media object to that? Can you give me a code sample